# Problem with no sound coming from right speaker ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I've two Bose Companion 2 Series III speakers from a former computer. They work perfectly on a PC with windows but the right one doesn't work on my System 76 PC which runs off Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried connecting the jack via the output at the back and front.

I've tried headphones via Jack at the back and they work fine on both. As far as I can see it is not a hardware problem.

I've looked at Alsamixer. The sound is not working on S/PDIF at all and although I can toggle the mute on this I can't increase the volume level as I can the others... so I have to connect via 'lineout' which is where my problem is at I guess. I've tried to look up old posts on this but not sure they work for me.

I've just noticed that the right speaker is working when it comes to some youtube videos but it still doesn't work when I run the test on 'sound'

Comment: It may sound obvious but have you checked in Ubuntu Sound settings? You can adjust the balance and also test the left/right channels. What is the result of that?

Comment: I have checked there - ubuntu sound settings are rather limited. They don't provide controls on either speaker. when I go into alsamixer it shows the sound maximal on either speaker.

Comment: I don't really understand the whole alsa & pulseaudio thing and I have not used alsamixer but I do use pulseaudio, so the only other suggestion I have is to download `PulseAudio Volume Control` from the Ubuntu software center (I see v4.0 there) and check settings there. I only say that as I had exactly your issue a while ago with a DIGITAL output signal. My `output device` in Pulseaudio volume control was one day set to silence for some random reason but I was still getting output coming out the left speaker. I put the volume output back to 100% and all was well again.